# Why does my action not return a view?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this page, where I select an item from a dropdown list, and an ajax call passes along the selected parameter to a new action in my controller, like this:

```
function select(e) {
    var unit = $("#unitList").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/Reports/UnitRunReport/")';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { selectedUnit: unit },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //
        },
        error: function () {
            // 
        }
    });
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
public class ReportsController : BaseController
{
    public ReportsViewModel Model { get; set; }
    //
    // GET: /Reports/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Model = new ReportsViewModel
                    {
                        Units = UnitClient.GetListOfUnits(true, "")
                    };

        return View(Model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UnitRunReport(string selectedUnit)
    {
        var unit = Convert.ToInt32(selectedUnit);
        Model = new ReportsViewModel
                    {
                        UnitRuns = RunClient.GetRunListForUnit(unit)
                    };

        return View(Model);
    }
}
```

I have to separate views for the two actions (Index and UnitRunReport). When debugging, it passes along the correct parameter to the UnitRunReport action, and moves through the `return View(Model)` statement. Could someone please explain why I'm not redirected to the new UnitRunReport View from the Index page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in an ajax call.  The ajax call will not redirect the page.

Redirect to the get method instead:

```
window.location = "@Url.Content("~/Reports/UnitRunReport")?selectedunit=" + $("#unitList").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not redirected because you are making the call using ajax.  This by definition means that the page will not change.  The result of the ajax call (in this case the ActionResult returned by the UnitRunReport method) will be returned into the data parameter of the success delegate you are providing to jQuery.

You could fix this by passing in a success delegate to swap the html on the page (or in an element on the page with the result of the call) e.g.  If you had an element with the id dataElement then use this in you success callback

```
success: function (data) {
        $("#dataElement").html(data);
    }
```

Note you are returning html back from your controller method.  You may want to return a json model and bind that to your page using a library like knockout.

If you want to actually redirect to the page rather than making an ajax call like you are currently doing then you need to set the window.location property when the user changes the selection in the dropdown.  This will cause the whole page to reload and render the view that UnitRunReport returns into a new page.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are making a ajax request which will not redirect the page but just read the data from the action.

Secondly, you are requesting for the json result which will give you the json data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to get JSON data back rather than a view, which is typically HTML.  So your controller should look like the following.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ReportsViewModel Model { get; set; }
    //
    // GET: /Reports/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Model = new ReportsViewModel
        {
            Units = UnitClient.GetListOfUnits(true, "")
        };

        return View(Model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UnitRunReport(string selectedUnit)
    {
        var unit = Convert.ToInt32(selectedUnit);
        Model = new ReportsViewModel
        {
            UnitRuns = RunClient.GetRunListForUnit(unit)
        };

        return this.Json(Model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

You can test the data coming back in your javascript by doing a console.log.  Also instead of doing Url.Content try Url.Action because your routes may not be setup correctly and url.action will make sure that the correct route will get generated.

```
function select(e) {
    var unit = $("#unitList").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var url = '@Url.Action("UnitRunReport", new { controller = "Home" })';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { selectedUnit: unit },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            // do something with the data coming back
        },
        error: function () {
            // show some sort of message
        }
    });
}
```

To view the console just hit F12 to get your tools to pop up in your favorite browser (I'm still a firebug fan).  Just be careful about deploying anything with console.log into production, these days it doesn't usually matter because people have newer browsers but you may still get those one or two that will slip by and have issues.  If you want to keep the code in there and put it into production you can launch a script with your pages into production to override console.log

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console = {
        log: function (s) {
            // empty method to override console
        }
    };
</script>
```

Put that in your site.master and remove it during development, you can keep all your console.logs and when going to production they'll stop showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're doing an Ajax call to the action method, so the view will be returned in the data parameter here: `function (data)`

It will not redirect the browser.